# Multiple image data publishing services and controls using GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, limitations

A project needs to manage massive image data (like satellite images), and publish it as a service for use on the web side, and control the display of some part of the image on the web side. Tessellation data sets can solve this requirement. My current idea is to publish each image as a layer, packaged as a group of layers. The data volume is in the millions.

How many layers can the geoserver service support at most?

Comment: The number of layers that geo-server can handle does depend on the machine specs that you are running geo-server on.

Comment: Do I need to restart the geoserver service every time you add a new layer？

Comment: you would probably be better using an image mosaic and a single layer

Comment: No, it's not necessary to restart the geoserver everytime publishing the layer.

Answer (score 1):

For that use case you likely want to use the image mosaic plugin, see the documentation and tutorials at:

- https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/
- https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adding_data/mosaic.html
- https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/multidim/imagemosaic/index.html